# PAN over Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Greetings. I am attaching one image in this post where I have drawn few components. My doubt is that whether what I drawn is possible in iOS or not. In the end what I want to achieve is, sending message from component 1 to 3 (3 to 1 also) and component 2 should not have any intelligence.[image]

Comment: You will need an app running on the iOS device to do this.

Comment: That app I will make. But is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, But what do you mean "component 2 should not have any intelligence"?

Comment: Due to design change, above query is different now. I will post a different query. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911316/pan-over-bluetooth-profile-viewer